# Como parsear correctamente un json en php

Tags: php, algoritmos

Tengo el siguiente código que testea una dirección url, este me retorna un objeto `JSON` pero no puedo acceder a sus datos. Deseo acceder al dato `listaMesa` especificamente, y mostrar solo los datos que tiene contendido:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
$ch = curl_init();
//$i es el numero de carnet, lo pueden probar con postman si no confían.
for($i=0; $i<13;$i++)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//La siguiente linea es la pagina del trep, lo pueden cambiar por computo si desean
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://computo.oep.org.bo/resul/mesaElector/$i");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$resp=curl_exec($ch);



$json=json_decode("[$resp]");
//    aqui deberia de ir un if, pero me da error al utilizar $json->listaMesa o $json["listaMesa"]
    var_dump($i,$json);
    echo '<br>';    

}
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Como Acceder a los datos de un JSON parceado para mostrar solo los datos que tienen contenido?

Comment: ¿Puedes intentar con $json[0] y mostrarnos el resultado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los errores que tienes son:

- Debes indicar a `curl` que necesitas que devuelva los datos (*y no que los imprima*) utilizando la opción [`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php).
- Solo debes pasar la variable `$resp` a la función `json_decode`.

Luego necesitas:

- Agregar un `if` para validar que el arreglo `$json->listaMesa` no esta vacío.
- Para recorrer el arreglo `$json->listaMesa` puedes utilizar `foreach`.

#### Solución:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
$ch = curl_init();
//$i es el numero de carnet, lo pueden probar con postman si no confían.
for ($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++) {

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://computo.oep.org.bo/resul/mesaElector/$i");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($resp);
    // Si la mesa no esta vacia
    if (!empty($json->listaMesa)) {
        foreach ($json->listaMesa as $obj) {
            $mesa = $obj->mesa;
            echo 'ID: ' . $mesa->id . ' - #Mesa: ' . $mesa->numMesa . "<br/>\n";
        }
    }
}
curl_close($ch);
```